# Cars vs vehicles

Tags: discussion, tags

Considering that not all [vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle)s are [cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars), I went ahead and tagged a number of questions with [cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars), a topic I'd argue is important enough to warrant its own tag, as opposed to the more generic [vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle), which would include bicycles, motorcycles, boats, aircraft, which would probably be more suited for vehicle intercomparisons.

Answer (score 3):

I think Nate's suggestion to change the 'vehicle' tag to 'automotive' is good but I'm not sure if automotive is a term that is commonly known to non-native English speakers so I'd rather change it to [motor-vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-vehicle).

I've posted this as an answer so people can vote on and we can see which tag people prefer.

Vote for this answer if you want to change [vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) to [motor-vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-vehicle)

Vote for [Nate's answer](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/144/99) if you want to change [vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) to [automotive](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automotive)

Comment: Wasn't it Nate's suggestion to change "cars" to "automotive"? While it may make more sense, I would be confused if I wouldn't find the tag "car" in here (as a non native speaker).

Comment: @boo2060 I don't think so. Nate's 3rd sentence contains a link to questions tagged 'vehicle' and he then continues that he thinks it should be migrated to 'automotive'.

Comment: Oh, alright. My bad then :) .. thanks for clarification.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear (edited).  Yes, THelper's reading was correct ... I was suggesting replacing `vehicle` with `automotive`.  Not because those two are equivalent, but because I thought `automotive` was useful, while `vehicle` was not.  I think `car` should stay. In my locale, `motor-vehicle` actually refers to boats, too, which I think won't share much in common with car/truck questions.  But, I think whatever term is most familiar to the widest number of people is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd support keeping the tags separate. [This pedal powered car](http://inhabitat.com/human-powered-car-can-go-30-mph-while-driving-uphill/) is neither a motor car nor an automotive, yet it is clearly still a vehicle.

From the perspective of a user who might search the site, tags like [electric-vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle) or [renewable-transportation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewable-transportation) may help distinguish between different types of questions. Depending on the question, one of these may be better than [vehicle](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle).

It's a shame actually that we don't have a tree structure of tags, as that would greatly help provide logical links between similar subjects...

Comment: I like the idea of a tag ontology, but I just found out something like this has already been discussed on [meta stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92788/164138) 2 years ago and [a similar proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2781/164138) has been declined.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would consider `automotive` to be a better term, for the types of questions that concern both cars and trucks (fuel efficiency, alternative fuels, engine technologies, etc.)

I have a hard time seeing how `vehicle` is really a very meaningful tag, as there isn't that much that boats, trains, planes, cars and trucks have in common.

As I think [there's only 5 questions in the vehicle tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle), it might make more sense to migrate this to `automotive` sooner rather than later, before site traffic increases much.

*Disclaimer*: I'm a speaker of American English, so if that term isn't equally as applicable in other English speaking countries, I'll gladly retract my suggestion.